# How to create embed script file from script file with certficate

Tags: linux, script, ssl, certificate, embedded

I have one certificate test script file,

**Checking_file.sh**

```
file ="/var/cert.pem"
openssl x509 -checkend $(( 86400 * $DAYS )) -in $file > /dev/null
```

its works file, But,  I don't want to share my certificate to client, I need to add certificate to `Checking_file.sh`,  then embed  `Checking_file.sh` and sent to client.

**what i did:**

I follow this [document](https://lembra.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/how-to-generate-a-bash-script-with-an-embeeded-tar-gz-self-extract/) convert cert.pem to cert.tar  and extract via script its throw below error:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**After Add cert.tar.gz to example.sh file:(Secound File)**

I tried only convert cert.pem to cert.tar.gz and added to example.sh file. after run this script, cert.tar.gz is not extracted. its throw above error.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Extracting file into `pwd`"
    # searches for the line number where finish the script and start the tar.gz
    SKIP=`awk '/^__TARFILE_FOLLOWS__/ { print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0`
    #remember our file name
    THIS=`pwd`/$0
    # take the tarfile and pipe it into tar
    tail -n +$SKIP $THIS | tar -xz
    # Any script here will happen after the tar file extract.
    echo "Finished"
    exit 0
    # NOTE: Don't place any newline characters after the last line below.
    __TARFILE_FOLLOWS__
    \8B\00\CA\E58Y\00\ED\D5I\8F\B36\F09\F3)\E6\8E\DA\00 $z\B01˰&p\A9[\92\B0xȧ/\F3\BE=t\91Z\A9RUU\F2\EFb\C9\FC\85\B7\D3vY\FEs\93\94y;t?\DE\F3\E6\ED_\C0,\B6<\FFղ[^\F8m\FB\85۰\FC\BBfY\9E㹵\C0\BE1,ǳ\C2\DB;\F3oL\E6\8F\C6~H\9E\EF\EFoϤ\E2\FE*\F7w\CF\FF\A7~\F8eU\B3\DE%\D9\F55E\93\80/\EB\A5LMCU%I\A0MJ\805J
    J/`\C1\B2~\\EA\AB*b\A7W\00Ӎ\B0":\CE6\98\ECD\F9\ACn3o\F9\8C\AE\9B\EE\EF\BF\82!\8AO:\93\E3{\C4)L\ECA\98\9D\DC\EE\BC\D6\EFپ\C6\FBKj\99~\8A)i\9C\E9ˌ\89\9C\CD\F1\AB\F3\95\E2\DF\F5U\805\DD\ABί#C\BD\CD8qN\D6\D6\9F\E0D\A5\AD\FB2v\8A\9A\FAS\A9@\00K+\84\C04Q\90\AD\97ў)\AB\DFRU\9C\B3\BD\89\CBR\BE\9A\80Q%\EF\A1z\DAy\8DR\C0    \00\D8ha\F08\80n\D9G\9A\CF\D1z7>\8AZ\AB\85\FDg\F5l\F4\8E1\F0\C3?\D98h\9B\93\F6\8A\D8\F7bf\89\F26\90Ϣq}\A9\F3\CA\FD~5\A1̩bqm\FA\CBkZ\8F\E9\A1\DC${'\C9\E5ї\F6\82,\8B\E0c\F6N\D94u\FB\D1˹\83%\ACQ\9E\D7"\ADJ\E7Pg\8F\DE\F3\E6\D4-Μy\CF[\E5Uo\89\A5\D7 @\BB\l\F32z\AA\CEΥ\D2\CC\DD\F6\C5\F5\B2\C7]\D1P\F1\E1\95\95X\AD\9B/\8Bл\B7y@?\C7Lt\EE\C1p\94\C3\F3\AAō\DBRN5\82c|R\F3\E3\C1\A0\AF짽+>\9E\DD\D0BE\B0\E0~=\A9\E7\B0T:\B0\DȀ\B2i\CC}\B7a*\CFP\91\95\CD\FA\95\A2\F3.v\AF'ZM\FC&\CFZn0\92n\E7zy\AEeR'\DA/\EF\B6\CD,\94'1vAiB\00ԪL\&\DE\E3Q\A1\CBT\96x#\C0\E3p\F6\DC\E6j`E+N\D6Fd\E2\F4\D2\CE7\D8a\B4\84\97\AC\9C\FD
    .Q\80e\B8z\9B\FA:\F7\BD\B3\83\A0\D8\C9\CB\F9K \8D\F0\DE\F9\B6!\8CdEMm\BA׭\DCRSي\EE<\BA\B8|\EDTJ\92zu\A9.o\84\C8Ħ&X\96OX\CA
    tR\A2\A8J\F6.\93\A2n2\B8\8E<\B6\8A<\9EM\B9\EF\85F\A53?\9C9\FDnp\D6\C5\E0\C4*]\8C\9CH?t\B1v\99R8\B2\80\96"\83@2v\9Ft\B2\AD>\A2\DBޘ\E5\FB̩\DD\F58\ADj7^\B92+7\E8\E6\9C\CB\C2\C6\D9NkN:\B0:\8C\EE\9B,2
    g\95\EAR\CBh\C7؊2\C3\E1Tۼ\D6"jE\8F\88\D1.\C9
    \E9&\B8[\8D]\9D\E3\D1\E3\B1\F0\C6"\CDަ\B2"\c$\F4\B1\EEDɇw\EC\B7R\9F="<\A8\854\BA\AFe\FDU\E8vd\87b\9C}\CC\EFy\F5\C9o'\FAѴw\BA\FD,Y\BC\E9ra\E2F\B3\CB\C4m\B6fݴf\D4\D5D\DF\AA\F7G\B8\FCo\A4A
    \B4\F6쯥\AD\E4\C0\9B3\C5\EB\A3h}\B9\BB\97GzK\CF\\90]+\BA|o\9Dv[\96OUͣ\DF\A6ș\E1\E0\F5OP\B5\9Ez\D7\E5R\A3\93fY\8E\C3ʆb\D9&    <Ӄqk9a\D4r\E2U\AA\D1˟\A8o\B7\9Bl\A1?\DDx\FF\F5eLAAAAAAA\F1\FCn\A1K\00(\00\00
```

Suggest me How to do that or any other way to do this.

Comment: Please show Your second version of `Checking_file.sh` file.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup I updated my question

Comment: Check Your `extract.sh` file. The last line must be `__TARFILE_FOLLOWS__`.